# Crowdsourcing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, crowdsourcing

I'm wondering if there is an option for crowdsourcing in QGIS.
I need something similar to what is Survey123 in ArcGIS.
I know that with QGIS I can use QField, but it's not what I'm looking for.
I need a tool that would allow users/general public to fill out a form and send a picture/location... If they can do it within a webpage (without installing an app) even better.

Comment: This is a paid for platform https://www.giscloud.com/how-it-works/ but do you have a budget to stick to?

Comment: thanks for letting me know.
However, I'm working for free, and the client is a no-profit, so I need to use something that is free of charge.

Comment: I volunteer for a non-profit and we use the Mergin Maps app to collect field data by volunteers.  Small nonprofits can be granted a free licence by Mergin's parent company, Lutra Consulting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look into this